# How to convert this page to utf8 (with curl)

Tags: php, mongodb, encoding

This is the page: http://www.stats.betradar.com/s4/gismo.php?&html=1&id=1828&language=tr&clientid=35&child=1&childnodeid=1819

I've tried everything for 14 hours. and couldn't find any solution.

I have to take datas with curl and transform them to utf8 and insert to the MONGODB.

But it doesn't happen. everytime, there becomes some problems.

Please, what should I do?

(when u look with view-source: there's some characters were changed like: ü=ü İ=İ Ş=&#350 etc.)

Comment: have you tried iconv and uft8_encode?

Comment: Obviously you didn't try everything otherwise you'd not be asking it on here.

Comment: @semmaye, yeah i've tried and it didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

All non-ASCII characters on this page are encoded as HTML entities / character references. Use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode them or an XML parser that will do that for you.

Comment: i'm still having problem. i've used html_entiti_decode and than insert datas to mongodb. and mongodb doesnt define again

Answer (score 0):

only str_replace can solve my problem. and this is not a stable fix.
if I find all different characters and add them to the "fix list" it can solve.

this is so hard